# Проверка логического выражения заданного в виде строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как выполнить проверку логического выражения заданного в виде строки и передать параметры в функции указанные в выражении?

```
str = "((func1 and func2) or (func3 and func4) or func5)" 
func1_params={"a":"1"}
func2_params={"b":"2", "c":"3"}
func3_params={}
func4_params={"d":"5"}
func5_params={}
if(str == True):
    print("ok")
else: 
    print("bad")
```

где `func1, func2, func3, func4, func5` - функции Python, которые возвращают `True` или `False`, а `funcX_params` - параметры передаваемые одноименным функциям для проверки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде есть три проблемы:

1. В выражении в переменной `str` имена функций, но не их вызовы;
2. Крайне неудобный способ хранить параметры;
3. Выполнение "динамического" кода - это всегда небезопасно.

Если на эти проблемы закрыть глаза, то можно было бы выполнить выражение, оперируя `globals()` и `eval()`. Но если делать по уму, то как-то так:

```
import ast


def func1(a):
    return True

def func2(b, c):
    return True

def func3():
    return False

def func4(d):
    return True

def func5():
    return False


# Список обрабатываемых функций
functions = [func1, func2, func3, func4, func5]
# Параметры функций
params = {
    'func1': {'a': '1'},
    'func2': {'b': '1', 'c': '3'},
    'func3': {},
    'func4': {'d': '5'},
    'func5': {},
}

# Выражение
expression = '((func1 and func2) or (func3 and func4) or func5)'

# Парсим выражение в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево
tree = ast.parse(expression, mode='eval')

class ExpressionValidator(ast.NodeVisitor):
    # Разрешённые узлы
    ALLOWED_NODE_TYPES = set([
        'Expression', # Выражения
        'Name',       # Идентификаторы
        'Load',       # Переменные
        'BoolOp',     # Бинарные операции
        'Compare',    # Сравнение

        'Str',        # Строки
        'Num',        # Числа
        'Tuple',      # Кортежи
        'List',       # Списки
        'Dict',       # Словари

        'Eq',         # Равно
        'NotEq',      # Не равно
        'Gt',         # Больше
        'GtE',        # Больше или равно
        'In',         # Входит
        'NotIn',      # Не входит
        'Is',         # Является
        'IsNot',      # Не является
        'Lt',         # Меньше
        'LtE',        # Меньше или равно
        'And',        # Логическое 'И'
        'Or',         # Логическое 'ИЛИ'
        'Not',        # Логическое отрицание
    ])

    def __init__(self, allowed_names=None):
        if allowed_names:
            self._allowed_names = set(allowed_names)
        super().__init__()

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if hasattr(self, '_allowed_names'):
            if node.id not in self._allowed_names:
                raise ValueError('Name access to "{:s}" is not allowed'.format(node.id))
        return self.generic_visit(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        nodetype = type(node).__name__
        if nodetype not in self.ALLOWED_NODE_TYPES:
            raise ValueError('Invalid expression: "{:s}" not allowed'.format(nodetype))
        return super().generic_visit(node)


# Проверяем, что в выражении нет небезопасных операторов
validator = ExpressionValidator()
validator.visit(tree)

# Компилируем дерево
code = compile(tree, '<ast>', 'eval')

# Выполняем код
# передавая в контекст результаты выполнения функций
result = eval(code, {f.__name__: f(**params.get(f.__name__, {})) for f in functions})

print(result)
```

Comment: Задача - написать простой движок, который мог бы из конфиг файла загружать пользовательские функции с предустановленными параметрами. Пользователь сам будет разрабатывать и или подключать нужные ему функции из отдельныых файлов библиотек. Нужно что-то функционала плагинов, где плагины будут создавать сами пользователи.

Comment: Просто такие задачи не решаются. Как минимум вам понадобятся модули [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) и [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) для динамической загрузки, проверки и обработки пользовательского кода. Но лучше взять что-нибудь вроде [RPLY](https://rply.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) и написать интерпретатор для [DSL](https://w.wiki/5Dj).

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Хочу начать с простых вещей.